# Правильные названия классов в Java

Tags: java

Всем привет.
Страдаю от неумения правильно придумывать названия своим классам. От этого так же страдают и коллеги=)

Вот есть какой нибудь сборник правил как назвать правильно класс. Понятно что он должен раскрывать суть работы класса, но то как я понимаю его работу может отличаться от того как его работу понимает коллега. Это от части говорит что сам класс не правильно спроектирован но тем не менее.

Вот допустим, у меня есть класс который нужен мне для того чтобы сгенерировать html страницу, и поместить ее в темповую директорию jboss, чтобы метод REST возвращал ссылку на эту страницу.

Собственно, я назвал класс buildingList.class
Все работает четко, но название блин не могу придумать.

Comment: "Придумывание названий переменным и классам может занимать до 70% работы программиста". (c) то ли Билл Гейтс, то ли Стив Джобс.

Comment: Сходу видно существенную ошибку в восприятии ООП: Вы описываете действие "сгенерировать html страницу", но имя пытаетесь придумать не для метода, осуществляющего это действие, а для класса.

Comment: Памятка: класс - существительное, метод - глагол. Это не только про названия, но и про то, что присходит. Цель "_сгенерировать html страницу, и поместить ее в темповую директорию jboss_" не может быть классом, это метод.

Comment: Информации мало, но из имеющейся следуют очевидные имена `Page` для класса и `save` для метода.

Comment: Вот еще полезная ссылка: [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). Там нет о том, **как** выбирать/придумывать имя, но есть о том, что это имя должно представлять. А понимая это уже намного проще придумать имя.

Comment: та же фигня))))

Comment: У вас три зоны ответственности. Generate, Save и GetLink. И вы хотите это в один объект запихнуть? Мгм, ну-ну. "В ИТ есть только две действительно серьёзные проблемы: как называть классы и как инвалидировать кэш" (С)

Comment: Если бы мне дали класс с именем buildingList.class, я бы для начала засомневался, что это таки класс (с маленькой буквы), а судя по его имени он представляется мне как список зданий...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну вроде бы написали все верно, тем не менее элемент недосказанности остался - спешу восполнить пробел (по следам документа [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) и своего опыта):

1. Имена классов: начинаются с большой буквы и должны состоять из существительных, типа 
   `BuildingList` в стиле *CamelCase*
2. Имена интерфейсов: начинаются с большой буквы и должно быть прилагательным, типа:
   `Buildable` - тоже в стиле *CamelCase*
3. Имена методов: начинаются с маленькой буквы и должны быть глаголами (в стиле 
   *CamelCase*), типа: `buildList`
4. Имена переменных: начинаются с маленькой буквы, типа: `myList` - в стиле *CamelCase*
5. Имена пакетов: все маленькими буквами, типа: `com.builder.list` - не в стиле 
   *CamelCase*, принято именовать пакеты доменным именем владельца, типа: `ru.padawan.builder.list`, хорошим тоном считается регистрация своего доменного имени и активно применять свое доменное имя с именами пакетов.
6. Имена констант: все большими буквами, типа: `MY_LIST_CONSTANT` - стиль *CamelCase* не 
   применяется, слова разделяются нижним подчеркиванием.

**CamelCase** (*буквально верблюжий регистр*) - это когда каждое новое слово пишется с большой буквы, типа: `HereIsCamelCaseExampleName` - `ЭтоПримерВерблюжьегоСтиляИменования`

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте БЭМ (Блок-Элемент-Модификатор) вот как пример статьи:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%AD%D0%9C

https://ru.bem.info/methodology/