# Main класс выдает ошибку: NotClassFoundException

Tags: java, классы, eclipse, методы

Код выдает ошибку.

Проверил код много раз, но почему-то не могу найти ошибку. Вот сама ошибка:

[image: сама ошибка]

```java
class Dog
{
    String name;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     Dog dog1 = new Dog();
     dog1.bark();
     dog1.name = "Барт";

     Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
     myDogs[0] = new Dog();
     myDogs[1] = new Dog();
     myDogs[2] = dog1;

     myDogs[0].name = "Фред";
     myDogs[1].name = "Джордж";

     System.out.println("Имя последней собаки - ");
     System.out.println(myDogs[2].name);

     int x = 0;

     while(x < myDogs.length)
     {
         myDogs[x].bark();
         x = x + 1;
     }
    }

public void bark() {

    System.out.println(name + "сказал ГАВ!");
}

public void eat() {

    //
}

public void chaseCat() {

    //
}
}
```

Структура папок и файлов:
[image: код, вот он]

Comment: в Java классы с большой буквы называют, и имя класса должно совпадать с именем файла. А у вас судя по скриншоту класс называется Dog, а имя файла pipka.java

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий спасибо, теперь работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переименуй либо `pipka.java` в `Dog.java`, либо можешь в коде класс `Dog` поменять на `pipka`. Дело в том, что название файла и название класса должны совпадать. Но так же необходимо называть классы правильно, соответственно, класс `pipka` должен начинаться с большой буквы: `Pipka`

Comment: Если назвать класс `pipka`, то такое название будет не отвечать [кодовому соглашению java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) 

Свод правил для названия классов уже обсуждался вод [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893254/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-java)

если интересно почитать свод правил по названию java классов на русском